# C++ how to extend a class and cast to appropriate type with same name

Tags: c++, polymorphism

First, let me preface this question with "I am new to C++"!  This will probably turn out to be something very simple and I'll feel pretty dumb but right now I could really use the help.  I know how to do this with an Abstract class but I can't use an Abstract class here.  Also, if there is a better way to do this, I'm open to suggestions.

---

I have a ClientCommand (base class) and a MasterCommand (extends base class)

[image]

The MasterCommand can do everything that the ClientCommand can do and a few more methods.

In my application, I want to use the same name for both commands.  If the object is a Client then it will be limited to only client methods.  If the object is a Master then it will have all the client methods plus the Master methods.

I know there has got to be a way to do this.

1. I am not casting it correctly
2. I am not constructing it correctly
3. Or there is something else I'm doing wrong

Here is my test code:

---

BASE CLASS HEADER:

```
#ifndef __OPCommand_H_
#define __OPCommand_H_

class OPCommand {

public:
    virtual void doSomething();
    void doClientStuff();
};

#endif //__OPCommand_H_
```

---

BASE CLASS BODY:

```
#include "OPCommand.h"

void OPCommand::doSomething() {
    // TODO - implement OPClientCommand::doSomething
    throw "Not yet implemented";
}

void OPCommand::doClientStuff() {
    // TODO - implement OPClientCommand::doClientStuff
    throw "Not yet implemented";
}
```

---

EXTENDED CLASS HEADER:

```
#ifndef __OPMasterCommand_H_
#define __OPMasterCommand_H_

#include "OPCommand.h"

class OPMasterCommand : public OPCommand {

public:
    void doSomething();
    void doMasterStuff();
};

#endif //__OPMasterCommand_H_
```

---

EXTENDED CLASS BODY:

```
#include "OPMasterCommand.h"

void OPMasterCommand::doSomething() {
    // TODO - implement OPMasterCommand::doSomething
    throw "Not yet implemented";
}

void OPMasterCommand::doMasterStuff() {
    // TODO - implement OPMasterCommand::doMasterStuff
    throw "Not yet implemented";
}
```

---

TEST CLASS HEADER:

```
#ifndef __TestMe_H_
#define __TestMe_H_


#include "OPMasterCommand.h"
#include "OPCommand.h"

class TestMe {

public:
    OPCommand* command;
    OPMasterCommand* masterCommand;

public:
    void startHere();
    OPMasterCommand* getMasterCommand();
    OPCommand* getCommand();
    bool isMaster();

};

#endif //__TestMe_H_
```

---

TEST CLASS BODY:

Pay close attention to the startHere method:

```
#include "TestMe.h"

void TestMe::startHere() {
    if (isMaster()) {
        masterCommand = getMasterCommand();
    } else {
        command = getCommand();
    }

    // Here - How can I point to or cast to the appropriate type, so I can use the same name everywhere in my code?

}

OPMasterCommand* TestMe::getMasterCommand() {
    if (!masterCommand) {
        masterCommand = new OPMasterCommand();
    }
    //command = dynamic_cast<OPCommand*> (masterCommand);
    return masterCommand;
}

OPCommand* TestMe::getCommand() {
    if (!command) {
        command = new OPCommand();
    }
    return command;
}

bool TestMe::isMaster() {
    return true;
}
```

I cannot get this to build.  Right now I'm getting a redefinition of 'OPCommand'

Comment: Please show the diagram of the desired class heirarchy.

Comment: First off, please show the complete error message, and the affected line.  Also, looks like you are including OPCommand.h twice in TestMe, and don't have a guard define in OPCommand.h

Comment: Also, you need ifndef/define/#endif in the "command" headers.

Comment: @Arkadiy - ifndef/define/#endif in the "command" headers made the errors go away, so now I am building.

Comment: ok, then - problem solved? Or do you still need a different class diagram?

Comment: @Arkadiy - I am sorry but there's nothing more to show in the desired class hierarchy.  I just created the test project to instantiate the masterCommand if master else clientCommand.  But I want to use the same name in my code (i.e., cmd).  The problem arises because there are two different types, OPClientCommand and OPMasterCommand.  How can I make cmd be either class?

Comment: Usually, when you have Command pattern, you have a single Command::doSomething() and 3 command classes: ClientCommand, MasterCommand and OtherCommand. Then you access all 3 via Command reference/pointer. Or you can add a Composite, combining Client and Common under 1 Command

Comment: @Arkadiy -  You are 100% correct.  The problem is that because MasterCommand is a ClientCommand (by extension).  If I create an Abstract command then I end up with multiple inheritance and a sort of circular dependency.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72587/discussion-between-arkadiy-and-lucy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the second part of the question: How to use a single base class and a single variable for all commands?

You need to look up the [Command](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command) pattern. In your case, you need to derive all of your classes from Command.

Also, if you derive MasterCommand from ClientCommand, there is no need for multiple inheritance: Command <= ClientCommand <= MasterCommand , that's it. MasterCommand isa Command because it's a subclass of ClientCommand.

Answer (score 2):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that since you're new to C++ you forgot your header include guards (that's a very common reason for the `redefinition of 'OPCommand'` error you're seeing).

Try putting something like this (changing the names for each header) in your header files:

```
#ifndef OPCOMMAND_H_included
#define OPCOMMAND_H_included

<original header contents>

#endif
```

Comment: Or if the compiler is recent enough `#pragma once`

Comment: @FredLarson: I think those answers fail to mention the big problem with `#pragma once`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696115/is-pragma-once-part-of-the-c11-standard for when `#pragma once` may fail.

Comment: @RedX: It's not so much a question of whether the compiler is recent enough. `#pragma once` cannot be implemented correctly in all situations, whereas traditional include guards are always safe. See the link I posted above.

Comment: Hey, Mark:  Thanks for the tip, you're right.  But my real question is I want to use the same name in my code (i.e., cmd).  The problem arises because there are two different types, OPClientCommand and OPMasterCommand.  How can I make cmd be either class?