# #pragma once position: before or after #include's

Tags: c++, pragma

In existing code I saw `#pragma once` be used after header `#include`s

```
//Some_Header.h
#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"

#pragma once

//implementations
```

Instead of

```
//Some_Header.h
#pragma once

#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"

//implementations
```

I thought it always needed to be like the second example, does it matter where your `#pragma once` is defined or does the preprocessor pick it up anywhere in your file?

**Edit**

I know `#pragma once` is not part of the standard and include guards are but that is not my question.

Comment: Do keep in mind that this feature, although widely supported by various compilers, is not a part of standard C++.

Comment: I know countless articles about this not being supported everywhere made that I couldn't really find the explanation I wanted.

Comment: I never use it, so I wouldn't know for sure - but I'd stick it as close to the beginning of the file as humanly possible. It simply makes more sense.

Comment: I always assumed so as well, it being sort of a translation of the include guard but seeing this I wanted to be sure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696115/is-pragma-once-part-of-the-c11-standard

as pragma once is not part of c++ standard.Instead of you can use following :

#ifndef _DEFINED_
#define _DEFINED_
/*
Your code
*/
#endif

Comment: To address the mark for duplication:
The other question talks about pragma once position vs include guards.
This question talks about pragma once vs header includes.
So I think it is incorrectly marked.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question and thus shouldn't be marked as such. Questions are unrelated at every level.

Comment: The behavior of `#pragma once` is not standardized (alas) and where it is placed in the file differs in behavior, say, for Visual Studio **CL.EXE** and for LLVM **clang++**.  If you want the same behavior for both, put `#pragma once` at the very top, *or* if you also (redundantly?) use header guards, just *after* the header guard, and before anything else (such as the `#include` block).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`#pragma once` should be placed before any headers are included. [Argument of #pragma directive is a subject to macro expansion.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805.aspx) So content of included headers can alter the pragma behavior:

```c++
// whatever.hpp
...
#define once lol_no

// your_header.hpp
#include "whatever.hpp"

#pragma once // warning C4068: unknown pragma
```

Comment: @user17732522 all `#pragma`s are implementation-defined.

Comment: @Caleth I was thinking that macro replacement in the first token after `#pragma` shouldn't happen because `#pragma STDC` is still supposed to work even if `STDC` is defined as a macro, but actually that doesn't matter since C++ does not define `#pragma STDC` and C specifically says that `STDC` is identified before replacement. So yes, there doesn't seem to be any question about standard-conformance. However, it still seems to be MSVC-specific behavior. GCC and Clang do seem to recognize `#pragma once` even if `once` is defined as a macro.

Answer (score 9):

There isn't really a complete answer on this question covering more than the big 3 compilers, so here's my attempt at a more complete answer.

## Summary

- **TL;DR:** If you care for portability, put it before any `#include` or `#define` statements that may conflict with it (e.g. put it first in the header).
- Supported by all major compilers ("the big 3" x86_64 compilers as well as intel, and embedded compilers)
- Placement *generally* does not matter as long as it reaches the preprocessor (e.g. not blocked by an `#if`-branch)
- Different compilers are *opinionated* on whether it *should be* first, without documenting *what happens if not*.
- *Most* compilers already detect include guards and treat it as a `pragma once` anyway, making the benefit largely just not creating a unique guard name.

Below is a quick, summarized guide:

| Compiler | Support | Documentation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Clang | Supported | GNU-compatible. Not documented, but [code shows it as normal preprocessing](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/Pragma_8cpp_source.html#l00405) |
| GCC | Supported | [gcc pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html) |
| MSVC | *Supported (1)* | [MSVC `one` pragma](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/once?view=msvc-170) |
| Intel (ICC) | *Supported (1)* | [Intel Compiler Reference Manual - Supported Pragmas](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/pragmas/intel-supported-pragma-reference.html#intel-supported-pragma-reference) |
| Intel (ICL) | *Supported (1)* | ICL uses MSVC front-end |
| Intel (ICX) | Supported | ICX is based on Clang |
| Texas Instruments | *Supported (2)* | [Reference Manual 5.11.23](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spnu151v/spnu151v.pdf?ts=1659691655913) |
| Texas Instruments (Clang) | Supported | This is a fork of Clang with all major features still in effect |
| ArmCC | *Supported (3)* | [Compiler Docs for `#pragma once`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0375/g/Compiler-specific-Features/-pragma-once) |

<sup>(1) - Supported, but is subject to macro expansion</sup>

<sup>(2) - Supported, but is documented to be expected at the beginning of the header.</sup>

<sup>(3) - Supported, but not recommended.</sup>

## Details

### GCC

From the GCC reference manual:

> If `#pragma once` is seen *when scanning a header file*, that file will never be read again, no matter what. It is a less-portable alternative to using ‘`#ifndef`’ to guard the contents of header files against multiple inclusions.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Scanning is done at preprocessing time, and so as long as the `#pragma` statement is visible to the preprocessor (not in an unreachable conditional block from `#if`), then it will take effect.

GCC's `#pragma once` is **not** affected by preprocessor substitution.

<kbd>[Live Example](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/nr917e1P8)</kbd>

### Clang

Clang's reference manual doesn't actually specify `#pragma once` so far as I can tell, however Clang is meant to be compatible with most, if not all, GCC builtins and features.

Viewing the source code for Clang's preprocessor phase indicates what you would expect; it handles `#pragma once` during preprocessing ([source](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/Pragma_8cpp_source.html#l00405))

```cpp
 void Preprocessor::HandlePragmaOnce(Token &OnceTok) {
   ...
   // Mark the file as a once-only file now.
   HeaderInfo.MarkFileIncludeOnce(getCurrentFileLexer()->getFileEntry());
 }
```

Like GCC, the placement of the `#pragma once` does not matter if it's first, and is not affected by preprocessor substitution.

<kbd>[Live Example](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/nPborPedf)</kbd>

### MSVC

MSVC's [documentation on `#pragma once`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/once?view=msvc-170) does not indicate where it belongs, just that it should be in a source (and has an example of it at the top).

As mentioned by others, when using `#pragma once` in MSVC, it is subject to preprocessor-expansion.

**With Substitution**

<kbd>[Live Example](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/nhrnsa8Wa)</kbd>

**Without Substitution**

<kbd>[Live Example](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/voW85erW3)</kbd>

### Intel (CL-Based)

When using the Intel compiler on Windows, the compiler uses an MSVC Compatibility mode (ICL). Although it's not documented in the [Supported Pragma](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/pragmas/intel-supported-pragma-reference.html#intel-supported-pragma-reference), though it **does** appear to be supported.
The placement does not appear to matter as well so long as the preprocessor reaches it.

ICL's `#pragma once` is subject to the preprocessor-expansion issue that MSVC experiences.

---

**Note:** `icl` is not supported on compiler-explorer, so no example is available.

### Intel (GNU-Based)

When using the Intel compiler on Linux or older macOS versions (ICC), the compiler uses a GNU compatibility mode.

Like above, it's not explicitly listed as a [Supported Pragma](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/pragmas/intel-supported-pragma-reference.html#intel-supported-pragma-reference), though it **does** appear to be supported in practice. The placement does not appear to matter as well so long as the preprocessor reaches it.

ICC's `#pragma once` is subject to the preprocessor-expansion issue that MSVC experiences.

**With Substitution**

<kbd>[Live Example](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/66nrT9c49)</kbd>

**Without Substitution**

<kbd>[Live Example](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/bYGMMf4ea)</kbd>

### Intel (Clang-Based)

The newer Intel ICX NextGen compiler is based off of Clang / LLVM technology. Behaviourally, this matches what Clang does.

Unlike other Intel compilers, but like Clang, thisdoes *not* suffer from the preprocessor-expansion issue.

<kbd>[Live Example](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/5rcTvGM5x)</kbd>

### Arm (`armcc`)

The `armcc` compiler [advises against `#pragma once`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0375/g/Compiler-specific-Features/-pragma-once), but does also provide an example of it existing after `#define` statements as an optional feature to work with inclusion guards.

Given the example, placement should likely not be an issue.

*It's unclear where this will experience any preprocessor expansion.*

---

**Note:** `armcc` is not supported on compiler-explorer, so no example is available.

### Texas Instruments (TI ArmCL)

As mentioned in the [reference manual](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spnu151v/spnu151v.pdf?ts=1659691655913), section 5.11.23:

> *This pragma should be used at the beginning of a header file that should only be included once.* For example:
>
> ```cpp
> // hdr.h
> #pragma once
> #warn You will only see this message one time
> struct foo
> {
>   int member;
> };
> ```

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

I haven't tested what happens if it's moved anywhere lower than the comment header, but the compiler only *officially* supports it **at the beginning of the file**.

I would suspect this should not matter, but cannot confirm.

*It's unclear where this will experience any preprocessor expansion.*

---

**Note:** `tiarmcl` (and other similar ti compilers) are not supported on compiler-explorer, so no example is available.

### Texas Instruments (`tiarmclang`)

This is a fork of `clang`, so it behaves the same as `clang` does.

The `#pragma once` in this implementation can be effectively placed anywhere the preprocessor reaches, and does not deal with preprocessor substitution.

---

**Note:** `tiarmclang` is not supported on compiler-explorer, so no example is available.

Comment: Awesome research work, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

`#pragma once` relates only to a file where it is placed. It matters to the compiler whether the file contains this pragma or not, and the position of it is unimportant. Therefore, the line with `#pragma once` can be placed anywhere in the file except for chunk of code that is excluded from compilation by the conditional preprocessor directives like `#if`, `#ifdef` and `#ifndef`. The excluded chunk of code is not parsed by the compiler and if it contains the preprocessor directive it has no effect.

Despite the fact that `#pragma once` can be placed at any line that is parsed by the compiler, I strongly recommend to follow the common practice and put `#pragma once` at the beginning of a header file.

Also, as @user7860670 mentioned, arguments of #pragma directive is a subject to macro expansion for MSVC compiler. But neither gcc nor clang support it:

- [example for msvc](https://godbolt.org/z/PhTxzrr1E)
- [example for gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/35rrKGeTb)
- [example for clang](https://godbolt.org/z/nd3hPv1x7)

Comment: _"It matters to the compiler whether the file contains this pragma or not, and the position of it is unimportant"_ This is not quite true. The `#pragma once` directive has to actually have been _reached_ by the compiler. if it hides behind an `#if` branch that isn't taken, then it doesn't take effect: https://godbolt.org/z/j3jecEd6v

Comment: You are right. If the block of code is excluded from compilation, it is not parsed by the compiler and if this block contains the preprocessor directive, it has no effect. I've updated the answer, thank you for your input.