# -std=c++11 undefined reference to vtable for -- Chess

Tags: c++, c++11, abstract-class, pure-virtual, deriving

I've an issue and I can't solve it (with google). As practice I write a program about chess.
There is a general piece class:

**pieces.h :**

```
#ifndef PIECES_H
#define PIECES_H

[...]

class piece{
public:
    bool dark; //0 = light, 1 = dark
    virtual std::vector<position> sovereign_movement();
    types identify; // enum types = {pawn, knight, king, etc...}
    position pos;
    std::vector<position> horizontal(position a);
    std::vector<position> vertical(position a);
    std::vector<position> plus90(position a);      //basic moves
    std::vector<position> minus90(position a);
    std::vector<position> Lshape(position a);

    piece() : identify(non), pos(position(1,1)) {}
    virtual ~piece() {}
};

class Pawn : public piece{
public:
    Pawn() { identify = pawn; }
    std::vector<position> sovereign_movement() {std::vector<position> sol; return sol;}
    ~Pawn() = default;
};
[...]

#endif //PIECES_H
```

And my **main** for testing:

```
#include "pieces.h"

int main()
{
   piece a;
   vector<position> test = a.horizontal();
   for(unsigned int i=0; i<test.size() ;i++)
       {
        cout << test[i].Pconvert() << endl; /// position::Pconvert() just make string
       }
return 0;
}
```

I've a **pieces.cpp** file what define the longer methods:

```
#include "pieces.h"
#ifndef PIECES_H
#define PIECES_H

std::vector<position> piece::horizontal(position a){
    std::vector<position> sol;
    for(int i = 1;i<=8;i++){
        sol.push_back(position(i,a.y));
        if(i==a.x){sol.pop_back();}
    }
    return sol;
}

[...]

#endif //PIECES_H
```

For this I get `undefined reference to piece::horizontal(position)` and `undefined reference to vtable for piece` for constructor and destructor in header file.

If i do my destructor abstract (`virtual ~piece() = 0`) I get:
`error: cannot declare variable 'a' to be of abstract type 'piece',  because the following functions are pure within 'piece': virtual piece::~piece()`

After that I've write default destructors all of derived classes, but writes same. After this I modify my main this way (`Pawn` is one of derived classes of `piece`):

```
int main()
{
    piece* a = new Pawn();
    vector<position> test = a->horizontal(a->pos);
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<test.size();i++){
        cout << test[i].Pconvert() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And then I get: `undefined reference to 'piece::horizontal(position)'` and undefined reference to piece's destructor in .h, so round is closed.

Could someone help me?
Thank you

Comment: The line `#ifndef PIECES_H` in your header file is rather significant, but you left it out. (OK, I'm assuming it's in your header file, since that would explain why nothing in `pieces.cpp` was compiled.)

Comment: How are you compiling your project?  Please show the exact compilation commands you're using.

Comment: If you are using VSCode did you modify your `tasks.json` to allow for compiling more than 1 source file since the default configuration supports building only the active file into an executable. If you are not please ignore the comment. The reason why I mention this is we see several dozen similar reports for VSCode each week.

Comment: @StephenNewell, I'm using codeblocks, and the default compiler of that. The only difference I made to switch on the C++11 in compiler settings.

Comment: @JaMiT Theres "anti-multipile" header guards in pieces.h and pieces.cpp too.

Comment: Get the header guards out of the .cpp file. Sorry I missed that last evening. I must have been tired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you include a header file, the contents of that file replace the `#include` line. So when `pieces.cpp` starts like this:

```cpp
#include "pieces.h"
#ifndef PIECES_H
#define PIECES_H

std::vector<position> piece::horizontal(position a){
    std::vector<position> sol;
    for(int i = 1;i<=8;i++){
        sol.push_back(position(i,a.y));
        if(i==a.x){sol.pop_back();}
    }
    return sol;
}

#endif //PIECES_H
```

it becomes the following after the pre-processor handles the `#include`.

```cpp
#ifndef PIECES_H
#define PIECES_H
class piece{
public:
    bool dark; //0 = light, 1 = dark
    virtual std::vector<position> sovereign_movement();
    types identify; // enum types = {pawn, knight, king, etc...}
    position pos;
    std::vector<position> horizontal(position a);
    std::vector<position> vertical(position a);
    std::vector<position> plus90(position a);      //basic moves
    std::vector<position> minus90(position a);
    std::vector<position> Lshape(position a);

    piece() : identify(non), pos(position(1,1)) {}
    virtual ~piece() {}
};
#endif //PIECES_H
#ifndef PIECES_H
#define PIECES_H

std::vector<position> piece::horizontal(position a){
    std::vector<position> sol;
    for(int i = 1;i<=8;i++){
        sol.push_back(position(i,a.y));
        if(i==a.x){sol.pop_back();}
    }
    return sol;
}

#endif //PIECES_H
```

Next, account for the `PIECES_H` macro. I'll comment out the preprocessing lines as I proceed.

```cpp
// #ifndef PIECES_H  -- PIECES_H is not defined yet, so proceed.
// #define PIECES_H  -- now PIECES_H is defined.
class piece{
public:
    bool dark; //0 = light, 1 = dark
    virtual std::vector<position> sovereign_movement();
    types identify; // enum types = {pawn, knight, king, etc...}
    position pos;
    std::vector<position> horizontal(position a);
    std::vector<position> vertical(position a);
    std::vector<position> plus90(position a);      //basic moves
    std::vector<position> minus90(position a);
    std::vector<position> Lshape(position a);

    piece() : identify(non), pos(position(1,1)) {}
    virtual ~piece() {}
};
// #endif //PIECES_H -- end of the earlier #ifndef
// #ifndef PIECES_H  -- PIECES_H is still defined from earlier. So skip ahead.
// All these lines are omitted from compilation
// #endif //PIECES_H -- end of the earlier #ifndef
```

The preprocessor just ripped out the contents of `pieces.cpp` because of the mis-use of header guards. **Header** guards belong in the **header** (see also [A: C++ Header Guard Syntax and Header Placement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59725301/c-header-guard-syntax-and-header-placement/59757744#59757744)). Take them out of your source file and it should compile as intended.