# Incomplete type in C struct

Tags: c, header-files

I have the below project structure:

file - a.h

```
#pragma once

 struct best_fit_struct {
    void *next;
    size_t size;
};
```

file - b.h

```
#pragma once
typedef struct mm_t {
  int type;
  union {
      struct best_fit_struct best_fit_mm;
  } per_mm_struct;
  void *memory;
} mm_t;
```

file - b.c

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
```

on compiling b.c using `gcc -c b.c`, it throws the following error

`file best_fit_mm has incomplete data type`

I have included `a.h` before `b.h`, so the ordering looks proper to me.

Surprisingly, if I include `a.h` inside `b.h`, things gets resolved.

Comment: @SouravGhosh corrected the typo in the question

Comment: Are "a.h" and "b.h" complete files? Are there no guards?

Comment: @peper0 I have used #pragma once in both of them

Comment: "so I dont want a.h to be included in it." - Not going to happen because of the error you're getting. How is the compiler to know how big to make the `union` if it doesn't have the definition of `struct a`?

Comment: ok realized that it is inevitable. @DarkFalcon but excluding that point, the compilation should be successful right?

Comment: There is missing semicolon after struct B. Is it just a typo in the question?

Comment: @peper0 typo. corrected

Comment: @FaizHalde: No, not unless you `#include "a.h"`. You can't just exclude that point. It is a rule of how the compiler works. It *cannot* compile without the definition of `struct a` no matter what.

Comment: That's two typos in the question so far. Could you copy/paste your [MCVE], please?

Comment: Compiles for me :) Are you sure you posted _exactly_ what you are trying to compile? If so, whats the output of `gcc --version`?

Comment: @DarkFalcon I mean excluding the public interface point

Comment: "Surprisingly, if I include a.h inside b.h, things gets resolved." <-- Then you answered your own question.

Comment: @DarkFalcon true. but why including a.h in b.c not compiling?

Comment: @FaizHalde is right that it's not a good style if you make headers not self-sufficient. You should not expect that someone include some header before another one. However it's true that if you include them in proper order it should compile.

Comment: @peper0 good guideline :) its been a horrible experience with code dependency in c

Comment: @FaizHalde, since it works for me, there is something you probably have not told us. Did you use gcc's `-E` flag to run only the preprocessor and look at the result to ensure that the includes are working as expected? I would bet that something else is including `b.h` before `a.h`.

Comment: @DarkFalcon updated the question with actual contents

Comment: ``size_t`` is not declared. Could you post a zip file with something that compiles and another zip with something that doesn't compile?

Comment: @FaizHalde: Now what is `data_id`?

Comment: @peper0 haha. just #include <stdlib.h>.

Comment: Sorry guys. It was indeed an absence of a header  file causing the issue. It's resolved. thanks! I should've posted my main.c file which only included the b.h file

Comment: @FaizHalde "using gcc -c b.c, it throws the following error" `file best_fit_mm has incomplete data type` and "It was indeed an absence of a header file causing the issue. ... I should've posted my main.c file" does not add up.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler has to know the entire layout of each data type. E.g. each field in aggregates, its offset (see [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof)), its size (see [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof)), its alignment (see [`alignof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types)) and its type.

So the compiler needs to know all of `struct a` (all the fields there) to figure out the layout of `struct b` (and that should be known at the definition point of `struct b`).

In practice, you'll better add `#include "a.h"` near the start of your header `b.h`. Of course you want to add [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your header files.

BTW, my preference is to avoid having many small headers, and I prefer have a few large ones, perhaps even one single common header for a small project (which you might *pre-compile* with `gcc`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40619764/841108) answer)

Sometimes, to debug preprocessor related bugs, you might ask to get the preprocessed form (e.g. using `gcc -C -E source.c > source.i` then look with an editor or pager inside `source.i`).

Comment: It's true, "you'll better add". However it should compile also in the case which author is asking about.

Comment: Your preference is troubling for unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

If file `b.h` uses items form file `a.h` then you must, by definition, include `a.h` within `b.h`

Comment: I'd like to comment on my own post: This does not answer OP's question.To my understanding `#include` is suppose to be a copy and paste. And if they are both copied and pasted in order in the .c file, why does it refuse to compile right? When the exact same thing is supposed to happen when `a.h` is included inside of `b.h`?