# Levels of visibility of symbols from a compilation unit - C

Tags: c, static, linker

In the below code,

```
/**********linkedListImpl.c ***********/

#include"list/list.h"

#if defined(LINKED_LIST)



/***************** Representation - start ******************/
  /* struct members are not visible to other .c files */
  static struct DListNode{

    void *item;
    struct DListNode *next;
    struct DListNode *prev;
  };

  /* Should be used in this .c file, only, so static */
  static typedef struct DListNode DListNode;
  static DListNode* createNode(void *);


  static struct List{

    DListNode *head;
    int size; /*size attribute is not part of list definition, but quick way 
                  to help user code */
  }List;


  .....
  #endif
```

---

```
/************ list.h ************/
#ifndef LIST_H /* Header guard */
#define LIST_H
#include"type.h"

/***************** Usage-start ************/

#if defined(ARRAY) || (LINKED_LIST)

  typedef struct List List;

#else
  #error "Wrong list implementation macro name !!!"
#endif

 ...
#endif /* LIST_H */
```

---

`List` type is declared in `list.h`, using `static`specifier,

```
  typedef struct List List;
```

and defined in `linkedListImpl.c`, using `static`specifier,

```
 static struct List{

    DListNode *head;
    int size;
  }List;
```

**Purpose**: To make `List` symbol available to user(`main.c`) only through a pointer(`List*`). User(`main.c`) should not be able to access `List` members in `main.c`.

In `linkedListImpl.c` Symbol `DListNode` is defined using `static` specifier,

```
  static struct DListNode{

    void *item;
    struct DListNode *next;
    struct DListNode *prev;
  };

  static typedef struct DListNode DListNode;
```

**Purpose**: For symbol `DListNode`, user(`main.c`) should neither be able to access `DListNode` members in `main.c` nor access `DListNode` object through `DListNode*` pointer.

Is this the right approach to hide the symbols `List` & `DListNode`?

Note: [Here](https://github.com/shamhub/Computing/tree/master/2_List/Implementation_C) is the complete code

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is it. It is called *opaque pointer*, and is used to hide the implementation details in the interface.

You may be interested by [What is an opaque pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553750/what-is-an-opaque-pointer-in-c)

Comment: `static struct List {...}List` does 2 things: i defines a structure `List`, and it also declares a `static` variable named `List` of type `struct List`. The word `static` concerns only the variable `List`, not the structure `List`. `DListNode` is written as a structure definition only, so the `static` word is useless here, as Basile answered.

Answer (score 3):

`static struct DListNode {` ... `};` is useless (it declares *no* variables of `struct DListNode`), but do declare the `struct DListNode` so is exactly the same as simply `struct DListNode {` ... `};`. It is like `static int;` declaring a list of 0 integer variables (notice that `static int x,y;` is a common way of declaring a list of two variables `x` & `y`).

A very common way is to define all your `struct` (and their fields) in public header files. Indeed, you are showing implementation details (but the compiler needs them to emit code).

A less common way is to declare a `struct` in a header file, and *only* use pointers to it (an [opaque pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer), like [Burns' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41307995/841108)). Then you might have an implementation defining the members of that `struct`. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41306509/841108).

A common example is the `FILE` from `<stdio.h>`. It is very likely to be defined as some `struct` but the field names are *conventionally* hidden and unused.

C programming is a lot about having good *conventions* and following them.

Answer (score 2):

What you have will work.

The `typedef` you have in the header file also acts as a **forward declaration** of the structure.  This is sufficient to pass around a pointer to the `struct` type but prevents the pointer from being dereferenced.

This allows you to keep the implementation details of the `struct` private to the .c file were it is **defined**.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to create opaque references in plain C the best way is to create 2 separate sets of headers, one with full declarations that will be used in sources that implement the 'methods', and another header with the opaque reference for user use.

This is the common strategy used in many OS's. Take a look to MS headers, they use HANDLEs to refer to objects. The HANDLES are created and passed to system functions, plain C simulation of C++ methods, that resides in modules using the full definition header.

Consider these 2 headers:

```
/* Internal header "InnerDList.h" */
  struct DListNode{
    void *item;
    struct DListNode *next;
    struct DListNode *prev;
  };
```

2nd

```
/* User header "DList.h" */
typedef struct DListNode DListNode;

DListNode *CreateDList(void * data, ...);
HRESULT    AddDListNode(DListNode *Dlist, void *data);
HRESULT    GetDListNode(DListNode *Dlist, void *SearchData);
...
```

Using the first allow the compilation of the functions that works on the DList structures, the second allows the use of DList's through an opaque object.

A variation to allow the use of full or partial definition could be the following: define a preprocessor symbol in the internal header and use this to conditionally define opaque objects.

```
/* Internal header "InnerDList.h" */
#define INNERDLIST 1    //We will use this symbol to modify user header

  typedef struct DListNode{
    void *item;
    struct DListNode *next;
    struct DListNode *prev;
  } DListNode;
#include "DList.h"    //Now include user header
```

In the User header:

```
/* User header "DList.h" */
#ifndef INNERDLIST
typedef struct DListNode DListNode;    //define only if not called by internal header
#endif
DListNode *CreateDList(void * data, ...);
HRESULT    AddDListNode(DListNode *Dlist, void *data);
HRESULT    GetDListNode(DListNode *Dlist, void *SearchData);
...
```

Comment: If I even do not want use of `DListNode` objects, through opaque object, in other compilation unit, what should be the approach?

Comment: @overexchange What you mean? That you want to have full definition in some other modules?

Comment: In my code, intention is to make `List`'s available through opaque pointer in `main.c`, but `DListNode`'s should not even be available through opaque pointers(completely hidden) in `main.c`. `DListNode`'s are purely used in `linkedListImpl.c` **only**. What is the approach for setting such level of visibility for  `DListNode` ?

Comment: @overexchange You have to create appropriate headers that selectively include what you want to make available through full definition, opaque pointer or nothing at all. I have added an example on how you can manage it. Is it clear enough?