# Using char in different files in C

Tags: c

I have 3 .c files main.c, fun1.c, fun2.c

```
char buff[50];//in fun1.c

char *arg;  //in fun2.c

arg = strstr(buff, "001"); //in fun2.c
```

I want to print `buff` in fun2.c but it gives an error `buff` undeclared, even though I declared it in fun1.h as `extern char buff[];`
There are functions in fun1.c and fun2.c each

Comment: Have you `#include`ed the files in the right order?

Comment: I include fun1.h file in fun1.c. Do i have to include it in fun2.c?

Comment: @saurabh It would be easier if we could roughly see how you are `#include`ing in each of your `.c` files.

Comment: #include "fun1.h" // in fun1.c

Comment: @RoadRunner I declared buff in fun1.h as extern char buff[];

Comment: Yes, you shall include `fun1.h` in `fun2.c` (and in all other files using symbols from fun1.c). That is the meaning of `.h` files.

Comment: @RoadRunner ok now i have included fun1.h in fun2.c still the error is displaying [undefined reference to 'buff' ]

Comment: Any symbol (function, variable) you want to use in a module (file) has to be announced to the compiler. This can be done by including a header with the declaration, or by declaring it explicitly. Note: the compiler knows nothing about any symbol in another module, unless you "tell" about it.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42135581/841108) to a related question

Comment: what command are you using for compiling the stuff? How do I get the feeling that you're compiling fun2.c and *linking it* into a single-module program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say what is wrong with your particular program, but here is an example which links 2 `.c` files with one `.h` file.

**1.** A header file `functions.h`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void func();
```

Where I use `extern` to provide definitions for another file.

**2.** Now, a `functions.c` file which uses this header file:

```
#include "functions.h"

void func() {
    printf("hello");
}
```

This needs to `#include` the header file, and use the function `void()` to print a message.

**3.** Finally, a `main.c` file which links it all together:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "functions.h"

int main(void) {
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

Which also needs `function.h` as it uses `func()`. You then can compile the code as:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g main.c functions.c -o main
```

You could also look into makefiles, which would reduce this long compilation line to simply `make`.

Comment: The compilation command should really be `gcc -Wall -g main.c functions.c -o main`