# header and header file

Tags: c++, c, header, language-lawyer

In http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf only `header` is mentioned.

In https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4727.pdf `header file` appears twice:

> [ Note: The non-member functions enable programmers to write code that can be compiled as either C or C++, for example in a shared header file. — end note ]

---

> Difficulty of converting: Semantic transformation. The type definitions must be moved to file scope, or in header files

**Edit:**
let's see the note in n4727:

> A header is not necessarily a source file, nor are the sequences delimited by < and > in header names necessarily valid source file names.

So, I still think they are different concepts.

My question is, what's the difference between `header` and `header file`? Now that `header` is not necessarily a source file, what else can it be?

Comment: Same thing.  Just slightly different terminology.

Comment: @SteveSummit please review my updates

Comment: Even if there is _terminological_ difference  .. that would be weakened by the fact that everything in c++ must and would converge to either header files  `.hxx` and  _source .cxx_ files .. be comfortable thinking no difference!

Comment: @MohammadKanan -- this is a `language-lawyer` question. The intent is to interrogate the Standard, not fall back on common implementation details.

Comment: @DavidBowling, I lean to consider this implementation .. otherwise _standard_ must take care of that

Comment: @DavidBowling My defense is this comment from _Deduplicator_: _The standard headers are part of the **implementation**, and found in an implementation-defined manner. They could, in theory, be part of the compiler (and not files in the filesystem) .._

Comment: @czxyl If you're worried about headers-that-might-not-be-files, the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261508/is-a-header-necessarily-a-file) explains it well.  (That question is tagged C++, but I think most/all of it applies to C.)  It's probably to admit the possibility they might not be files that some authors take care to call them *headers*, but it's still the same concept.

Comment: @MohammadKanan -- Yes, headers are part of the implementation, but the Standard does not appear to require that they be _files_. This is what OP is asking about. "Be comfortable thinking no difference" is probably fine, but doesn't address OP question which seeks further understanding.

Comment: @DavidBowling, yes if they could be _for instance_ part of the compiler .. or ..anything where it would be possible to _include_ them

Comment: Neither of your citations is normative: one is a note, and the other is in an informative Annex.  So formally there is no ground for claiming they are different.  Practically speaking, those passages address _application programmers_, who cannot make non-file headers.

Comment: @DavisHerring -- "formally there is no ground for claiming they are different": formally there are no reasons form claiming they are the same. [This answer from the duplicate provides an enlightening quote from the C99 Rationale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27262904/6879826).

Comment: @DavidBowling: My phrasing was careless.  The right thing to say is that, normatively, there is no phrase “header file” about which to ask the question.