# Why don't C/C++ have the include guard feature built-in?

Tags: c++, c, include

It's laborious to put an include guard in every header file. Most other language don't need it anyway. Python doesn't have 'import' guard.

Comment: Most modern compilers have `#pragma once`. Put this at the beginning of your header files and no more need to put an include guard.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why aren't include guards in c++ the default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260752/why-arent-include-guards-in-c-the-default)

Comment: Without any hints the preprocessor can't distinguish header files from regular translation units.

Comment: Feel free to join the ISO committee and put forward your idea :-) That is, after all, how changes are made to the language.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: There are many arguments pro and contra, but I'm sure it is not too hard to make the preprocessor file-aware, so this one is bogus, IMO.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis What do you mean _file aware_? How? Based on filename extension? That won't work.

Comment: File-aware: aware of the fact that a file is included, header or not. And yes, preprocessors could probably even detect different kind of files. If you say: this is for historical reasons, fine. If you say: because it is impossible, then I don't believe it.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis - specifying how to decide if an include file is unique on arbitrary file systems **IS** hard.

Comment: If it is so hard, then why can other languages, also on many different file systems, cope with it? I assume that on any of those, files have unique names.

Comment: FWIW, I am not advocating a change. But saying: "it is/was not possible" is a bogus argument, IMO.

Comment: Detecting the "unique" pathname of an included file is probably impossible.  Directories can be accessed via many paths (links, symbolic links) and then when you throw in network paths and share names the problem becomes impossible.  If the same header file is accessible by 2 or more paths which is the "real" one?

Comment: @m.s. Oh yeah, it was a duplicate question.

Answer (score 4):

C/C++ including is a textual thing.  It can be used multiple times successfully.

```
#define STUFF  EXPANSION1
#include "mydataset.h"

#undef  STUFF 
#define STUFF EXPANSION2
#include "mydataset.h"
```

Allows a macro data set to be filled out with differing behavior.