# Why duplicate include some header file in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c

```
#include<assert.h>
#include<stdio.h>
**#include<stdlib.h>**
#include<string.h>
**#include<stdlib.h>**
#include<time.h>
```

stdlib.h is included for two times, but why?

Comment: Copy and paste from another code base without checking? Forgetfulness?

Comment: You certainly don't need to. If you delete the later one, it is almost certainly going to work.

Comment: as far as i know, the preprocessor ignores duplicate headers, so no need to worry about it

Comment: Multiple includes are useful for code generation but in this case, it's probably just result of not-thoroughly-checked copy&paste or merge.

Comment: I always try to sort my includes alphabetically, which makes this error a lot easier to spot and harder to make. But, it's also harmless.

Comment: @mangusta No, it does not. It's [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) that are used against duplicit code inclusion, preprocessor is dumb and happily includes it.

Comment: There is exactly one non-idempotent standard header in C: `<assert.h>`, and in C++ additional the C++ adaptation `<cassert>`. Even for those, multiple inclusion does not make sense without changing `NDEBUG` between them.

Comment: because the original author wasn't paying attention.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no way to determine what the author was thinking when they wrote the code.

Comment: This code is part of a file in QFS.

Answer (score 3):

There is exactly one non-idempotent standard header in the C standard: `<assert.h>`.
C++ inherits that and adds its own adaptation: `<cassert>`.

Even for those, multiple inclusion has no effect without changing `NDEBUG` between them.

Your own headers, as well as headers from other libraries you might use, should use include guards (or the [unportable but often working `#pragma once`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1695807)).

If you sort your headers (include the implementation-files own header first though), you can easily eliminate duplicates and don't need to rely on that.

Comment: it's funny this being answered by Deduplicator!